# How to enable selection between multiple BasicTextField in Kotlin Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop, jetbrains-compose

As you can see here, there is a composable function available to use as a wrapper for Text functions:

```
SelectionContainer {
        Column {
            Text("test1")
            Text("test2")
            Text("test3")
        }
    }
```

However, it does not work with BasicTextField.

For more context,
I'm attempting to make the [CodeViewer](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/examples/codeviewer) editable and I don't want to use a single BasicTextField as they did in [Notepad](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/examples/notepad) for "[simplicity](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/blob/74d536dfa85ecbcabeff1ae8a3468ed064d10e32/examples/notepad/src/main/kotlin/window/NotepadWindow.kt#L34)".

I'm considering implementing something similar to `SelectionContainer` for my use case but I'm not sure if it's possible or even a good idea.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The idea of using SelectionContainer is basically with multiple child elements in this case Text but if you use Single BasicTextField you can still select everything that it contains...

Comment: Yeah, that's actually how I implemented it for now but according to a comment in their example "TextField isn't efficient for big text files" I believe there's no solution for now without going deep into the framework. maybe they implement something like `SelectionContainer` in future releases. I'll update this question if that happens. Thanks